# Deleting a user with photo and without it in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, delete-file

I want to delete a user but I only can if he/she has a photo if has not I got
Trying to get property of non-object. I want to delete either way. My code:

```
  public function destroy($id)
{
   $user = User::findOrFail($id);
  if(File::exists($user->photo->file)){
    unlink(public_path().$user->photo->file);
    $user->delete();
    Session::flash('deleted_user','The user has been deleted');
    return redirect("/admin/users");  
  }else{

    $user->delete();
    Session::flash('deleted_user','The user has been deleted');
    return redirect("/admin/users");

  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has no photo, `$user->photo` may be null so you will get an error when trying to access `$user->photo->file`. To prevent the error, you have to check if `$user->photo` is an object.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    if(is_object($user->photo) && File::exists($user->photo->file)){
        unlink(public_path().$user->photo->file);
        $user->delete();
        Session::flash('deleted_user','The user has been deleted');
        return redirect("/admin/users");  
    } else {
        $user->delete();
        Session::flash('deleted_user','The user has been deleted');
        return redirect("/admin/users");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first check if parameter exists and then use it to find image

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   $user = User::findOrFail($id);
  if(isset($user->photo->file) && File::exists($user->photo->file)){
    unlink(public_path().$user->photo->file);
    $user->delete();
    Session::flash('deleted_user','The user has been deleted');
    return redirect("/admin/users");  
  }else{

    $user->delete();
    Session::flash('deleted_user','The user has been deleted');
    return redirect("/admin/users");

  }


}
```